# Is there an easier way than nested iifs to count mismatched conditions in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, iif

The picture below shows a table of accounts and the outcomes that I want to count. Ie every time the account number is 106844 and the outcome is "MESSAGE" or "ESCALATION EMAIL" that should count as 1 where any other outcome counts as 0. What I would normally do is a horrible mess of iifs like

```
   sum( iif([account] = '106719' and [Outcome] in ('MESSAGE','ESCALATION_EMAIL'),1,iif([account] = '310827' and [outcome] <> 'ABORT' and 'CALL_OUTCOME_LB' in ("Call patched to Customer Care","Message Taken"),1,iif( ... , 0) as [Total Outcomes]
```

and so on but man it feel like there's got to be an easier way or one less prone to making a random mistake in the 7th nested iif and messing the whole thing up. Any ideas?

[image: input]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `iif()`.  It is a function brought into SQL Server for back-compatibility to *MS ACCESS*.  Why would you want to be backwards compatible to such a thing?

Use the ANSI standard `CASE` expression:

```
  sum(case when account = '106719' and Outcome in ('MESSAGE', 'ESCALATION_EMAIL')
           then 1
           when account = '310827' and outcome <> 'ABORT' and
                'CALL_OUTCOME_LB' in ("Call patched to Customer Care", "Message Taken")
           then 1
           . . .
           else 0
       end) as Total_Outcomes
```

I would also advise you to name your columns so they don't need to be escaped (why "Total Outcomes" became "Total_Outcomes").  That simplifies the code.

Comment: Just what I was after and a helpful hint too. Thanks.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I haven't seen any functional differences between the two, and the small performance testing which I did showed absolutely no difference. If there's a _need_ to be ANSII standard, so be it; however, most of the time there's no need for it, and the general rule for writing queries would be to enhance human readability - that would be my case for using the significantly shorter IIF syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a lookup table that has the Account and Outcome and use that? Then, as requirements change, you could update the lookup table and not worry about your code.

Comment: This is what I'd suggest. One row per account/outcome combination (so potentially multiple rows per account). Makes the query trivial to write *and* open to easy modifications later.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah... there is
The last parameter is for when the condition is false, everything else will fall in there.

```
SUM( IIF([ACCOUNT] = '106719' AND [OUTCOME] IN ('MESSAGE','ESCALATION_EMAIL'),1,0))
```